# Color legend does not show color in geom_pictogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am trying to create a waffle plot with 3 different informations: pictograms, colors and facets.

When I use geom_waffle, everything works (though for this question, I haven't made the plot very pretty, sorry). But when I use geom_pictogram and replace the fill parameter by the label parameter in the aesthetic, the color in the legend does not appear anymore.

any help much appreciated

I've tried explicitly to use guides, the limits argument in scale_color_manual, but nothing works.

--

```
fig3gout <- data.frame(value=c(30,20,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,50,
30,20,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,45,
35,15,6,4,5,3,3,2,0,27,
38,12,10,15,6,4,4,3,0,8),
phase=rep(c("Baseline","Deploying a","Deploying b and c","Consolidation"),each=10),
improvement=rep(c(rep("none",2),rep("a",2),rep("b",2),rep("c",2),rep("undiagnosed",2)),4),
measure=rep(c("treated","diagnosed"),20))
fig3gout$phase <- factor(fig3gout$phase,levels=c("Baseline","Deploying a","Deploying b and c","Consolidation"),ordered=T)
fig3gout$improvement <- factor(fig3gout$improvement,levels=c("none","a","b","c","undiagnosed"))
fig3gout$measure <- factor(fig3gout$measure,levels=c("treated","diagnosed"))
```

**waffle code:**

```
library(ggplot)
library(waffle)
ggplot(data=fig3gout,aes(values=value,fill=measure))+
  geom_waffle(size = 2.5, n_rows = 10, flip = TRUE,aes(color=improvement))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c(1,2))+
  scale_color_manual(name=NULL,values=c("#873600",
                                                 "#28B463",
                                                 "#7D3C98",
                                                 "#EC7063",
                                                 "#F0F3F4"),
                                                 labels=c("Baseline","QI a","QI b","QI c","undiagnosed")) +
  facet_wrap(~phase,nrow=1,strip.position="bottom")+
  coord_equal() +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(), 
        panel.spacing=unit(-.2,"cm",data=NULL),
        axis.text=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks=element_blank(),
        legend.title=element_blank(),
        legend.position = c("top"),
        legend.box="vertical",
        legend.box.just = "top",
        legend.key.size = unit(1,units="cm"),
        legend.margin = margin(2, 2, 6, 6))
```

[geom_waffle image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8C19.png)

**pictogram code**

```
ggplot(data=fig3gout,aes(values=value,label=measure))+
  geom_pictogram(size = 2.5, n_rows = 10, flip = TRUE,aes(color=improvement))+
  scale_label_pictogram(name=NULL,
                        values=c(diagnosed="user-plus",treated="user"))+
  scale_color_manual(name=NULL,values=c("#873600",
                                        "#28B463",
                                        "#7D3C98",
                                        "#EC7063",
                                        "#F0F3F4"),
                     labels=c("Baseline","QI a","QI b","QI c","undiagnosed")) +
  facet_wrap(~phase,nrow=1,strip.position="bottom")+
  coord_equal() +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(), 
        panel.spacing=unit(-.2,"cm",data=NULL),
        axis.text=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks=element_blank(),
        legend.title=element_blank(),
        legend.position = c("top"),
        legend.box="vertical",
        legend.box.just = "top",
        legend.key.size = unit(1,units="cm"),
        legend.margin = margin(2, 2, 6, 6))
```

[geom_pictogram image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjQLx.png)

Comment: I guess geom_pictogram doesn't take a fill aesthetic. You would need to pass a second color scale.

Comment: thank you. Adding a scale_fill_manual, or simply adding "fill" in the aesthetic argument of scale_color_manual does not work unfortunately.